# Retirar espaço em branco reportviewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer

tenho um `ReportViewer` que oculta o `TextBox` se caso esteja em branco, porém ao ocultar fica o espaço em branco no relatório. Os `TextBox` são posicionados verticalmente então quando algum esta `hide` fica um espaço entre eles. Alguém sabe como não deixar esse espaço em branco quando o campo foi ocultado?

Comment: ninguém consegue ajudar?

Comment: O relatório é gerado em HTML, e a altura do container dessa textbox deve estar com altura explícita. Você pode sobrescrever esse comportamento com CSS.